# Second NIC makes Gigabit Ethernet drop to 100mbit

Tags: nic

I got a computer hosting VMs. This computer has TWO gigabit Ethernet cards.
Whenever I connect the a cable to the second NIC, the speed of the first drops to 100mbit even though it is seen as a gigabit.

The second Ethernet card is not connected to the same network and is connected to 100mbit devices.

It seems Ubuntu replicates somehow, the behavior of the second card onto the first one...

The two interfaces are functional and they do their purpose, only that year 2000 speed is bothering me.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried manually specify all the network settings (gateway, dns servers bla bla)
Restarted the Eth interfaces and It worked... For some hours.

Right now it's back on 100mbits and won't budge.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

ifconfig output is:
enp4s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::8122:5c82:3b21:a23d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 50:3e:aa:06:39:9c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14540  bytes 1272337 (1.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12258  bytes 1205363 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp7s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::c742:4bcf:d27d:9432  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 40:b0:76:10:6a:a4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27718124  bytes 2129932327 (2.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18119055  bytes 24609216641 (24.6 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 17545264  bytes 382738749616 (382.7 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17545264  bytes 382738749616 (382.7 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ethtool output of the desired 1gbit interface:

Settings for enp7s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes

Ethtool of the other interface:

Settings for enp4s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try to force the NIC you know (or at least are pretty sure) is gigabit to gigabit. That command is  `ethtool -s enp7s0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on`. May or may not require sudo privileges. I dont know if that will work since Ubuntu seems to be forcing it back.

You could also just have some funky motherboard setup that actually just bonds those two interfaces together and auto-negotiates the lower speed as a result. What model motherboard and computer is it. Also, what are the NIC models?

Also, how are the NICs connected. Are they PCIe? Could you also please try resetting all of your settings to automatic, restarting the machine, and then posting what you see?